# Can I use Mathematica for the symbolic verification of cases of a general problem?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have never used Mathematica before, but I am contemplating using it to [solve this problem](https://fourierkingdom.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/a-jumping-fourier/) for a simple case of $f(x) = C, 1<x<2$ and $= 0$. I can easily get $\hat{f}$, the Fourier transform of $f$, without any help from Mathematica. From there, I intend to use it to verify the following statement.

[image: $$ $$]

for $a = 0,b = 3/2$.

I don't know anything about Mathematica. I would like your advice about going ahead with it. I speculate (am almost sure) there might not be any closed form expressions possible in this problem, so I am wondering if Mathematica's symbolic machinary can really crack this. Also, if one exists, I'd like to know which suitable package I need to buy.

EDIT : My effort

[image]

I need to evaluate

```
Limit[V[ω]/(((log[ω])^2)*(G[ω])), ω -> Infinity]
```

I don't know where should I paste this code and how can I evaluate this.
All the above code was pasted in a single cell. Please help me how to proceed.

Code :

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0,x<=1},{C,1<x<2},{0,x>=2}}]
ft[ω_] := FourierTransform[f(x),x,ω]
L[t_,ω_]:=Integrate[ft[α] Exp[I α t],{α,0,ω}, Assumptions->ω>0]
Lbar[t_,ω_] := Conjugate[L[t,ω]]
K[t_,ω_] := Integrate[L[t,α]*Lbar[t,α]*Abs[ft[α]],{α,0,ω}, Assumptions->ω>0]
P[t_,ω_] := Integrate[L[t,α]*Abs[ft[α]],{α,0,ω}, Assumptions->ω>0]
M[t_,ω_] := Integrate[Lbar[t,α]*Abs[ft[α]],{α,0,ω}, Assumptions->ω>0]
G[ω_] := Integrate[Abs[ft[α]],{α,0,ω}, Assumptions -> ω>0]
SI[t_,ω_] := K[t,ω] - ((1/G[ω])*P[t,ω]*M[t,ω])
dSI[t_,ω_] := D[SI[t,ω],t]
V[ω_] := Integrate[Abs[dSI[t,ω]],{t,0,3}, Assumptions->ω>0]
B[C] := Limit[V[ω]/(((log[ω])^2)*(G[ω])),ω->Infinity]
```

Comment: Can't you just do `Simplify[Limit[] == Sum[]]`?

Comment: @Feyre : Did you go through  the entire problem? I get to the expression under  the limit, after evluating several integrals. What you are saying is only the final step.

Comment: You're right, if it's a more extensive problem you should show what you have done so far yourself though.

Comment: @Feyre : The problem is essentially evaluating definite integrals and finally the limit. I have no acquaintance with mathematica and I need help to begin with and want toknow if its even doable. I have just downloaded mathematica trial version. Any tips to begin with?

Comment: So say, defining your function `L` with `L[t_, \[Omega]_] := 
 Integrate[ft[\[Alpha]] Exp[I \[Alpha] t], {\[Alpha], 0, \[Omega]}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Omega] > 0]` when `ft` is your fourier transformed function. Then you can call `L[t, \[Alpha]]`?

Comment: @Feyre : I men how should I start using mathematica, not the problem. I mean where should I type the source code, how to compile, etc.

Comment: I suggest you have a look [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/), you can bring up the documentation center by pressing `f1`.

Comment: Post code, not images of code. Copy and paste it like text, select it and hit the `{}` button to achieve the right formatting.

Comment: @corey979 : posted

Comment: You need commas before pretty much every `Assumptions -> \[Omega] > 0`. Adding that and evaluating the expression you were interested in one finds the limit is `0`. Another question, you have `log` in there. Did you want that to be `Log10` (log) or the `Log` (ln)? (Edit: it doesn't matter either way. I'd liekly need to understand the problem better to help and from your mathoverflow post about this the problem seems rather involved)

Comment: @MB1965 : The first two cells I need to replace 'x' with 't', its a mistake. Could you please check and also tell me how you have evaluated.

Comment: @MB1965 : Can you send me the code with commas?

Comment: I'll just edit the code in your post. It's a trivial change (`{\[Alpha], 0, \[Omega]} Assumptions -> \[Omega] > 0` becomes `{\[Alpha], 0, \[Omega]}, Assumptions -> \[Omega] > 0`). I just evaluated the definitions cell and the expression you posted as the one you need to evaluate). If you tried to evaluate it as was given it simply threw syntax errors.

Comment: @MB1965 : I too get zero. Looks like some bug. In the second cell, can you plot the function 'ft'. I guess its all becoming zero which it should not.

Comment: Looking at the definition of `ft` you have `f (x)` which explains your problem. It ought to be `f[x]`. Before you go much further you should really read a quick tutorial on Mathematica syntax and things. It will make your life much easier. Give these things a look ``Documentation`HelpLookup@"howto/WorkWithVariablesAndFunctions"``

Comment: @MB1965 : That was a typo. I am still not able to plot after rectifying ( to [. Could you please help with this step? Also please change 'x' to 't' in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51056/discussion-between-mb1965-and-rajesh-dachiraju).